# Hitting enter doesn't call the function; resets instead.

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple form that has a drop-down list with 3 options and a text box.
I need to check the values of both inputs in order to direct the user to the appropriate page. It works fine when I click by mouse on the "Go" button. However hitting enter reload the page!
The code was working before adding the drop-down list.. it is causing the problem to occur somehow!

---

```
 <select form="semester">
    <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
        <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
     <option value="Summer">Summer</option>

   </select>
 <input type="text" name="year" maxlength="4" size="30" onsubmit= " if(event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" />

<input type="button" id="btnSearch" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Go!"/>

 <script language="javascript">
    var e = document.getElementById("semester");
    var ee = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    function check(form)
    {
       if(ee == "Fall" || "fall"&& form.year.value == "2013")
        {               window.location="semester/fall13/categories.html"; 
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        alert("Not Available!")/*displays error message*/
                    }

                }
            </script>
```

Comment: Can you create JSFiddle to illustrate your problem?

Comment: `('btnSearch').click()` what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly do what AvinashW says:

```
<select id="semester" name="semester">
```

to prevent the form from submitting, do this:

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

Here's another mistake you are making:

```
if(ee == "Fall" || "fall"&& form.year.value == "2013")
```

should be

```
if(ee == "Fall" || ee ==  "fall" && form.year.value == "2013")
```

And if you dont mind, i made a page with the functionality you need but with my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <select id="semester">
        <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
        <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
        <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="year" maxlength="4" size="30" onkeypress= " if(event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" />

    <button id="btnSearch" onClick="Go()">Go</button>
</div>

<script>
function GetSelectedItem()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("semester");
    strSel=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    return strSel;
}

function Go(){
    selected = GetSelectedItem();
    if( (selected=="Fall"||selected=="fall") && document.getElementById('year').value=='2013'){
        window.location="semester/fall13/categories.html"; 
    }else{
        alert("Not available!");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3YhWL/)

Comment: Thanks .. But I don't want to reset when hitting enter.
I want to go the appropriate page by checking the input inserted by the user.

Comment: use the second part of my answer to prevent the form from submitting @user2968129

Comment: It worked because the tag <form> is not there .. I'm really thankful it took me 4 hours without finding a solution :)

Comment: @user2968129 man, the way you can actually thank him, is by accepting his answer..

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow .. I've just did :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is correction,

```
<select id="semester" name="semester">
```

onsubmit should apply to form ,not to input

Comment: Thanks I corrected this. 
I changed the place of the onsubmit but it is still not working.. The page resets when I hit enter

Comment: can you create sample jsfiddle?

Comment: try input button type to submit